# Как сделать так, чтобы были видны символ "\0"(конца строки) в vscode при дебаге?

Tags: c++, c, gdb

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот есть gdb в vscode как увидеть в переменной buf наличие символа \0. Он там сто процентов есть

Comment: А зачем его видеть, если вы уверены, что он там есть?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну в этой строке есть, меня интересуют другие. Просто я явно положил в эту '\0' чтобы убедиться, что gdb не отображает этот символ

Comment: Так, а тип у этих строк какой, `char *` или `std::string`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat char *, это чистый си

Comment: Тогда никак, думаю. Я бы еще понял, если бы там был тип `char [N]`. А с `char *`, дебаггер никак не отличит ваш `\0` от настоящего конца строки.

Comment: ¿Если это чистый С, то зачем тег С++? Ну и в таком случае `\0` как раз задает конец строки. Хотите смотреть, что там идет дальше - открывайте просмотр памяти.

Comment: я думаю, что автор вопроса имеет ввиду, что отладчик в большинстве случаев хорошо знает компилятор и может "угадать" истинный размер массива и показать его полностью. Ведь `char*` это не только массив символов aka строка, а и обычный массив, который вполне может содержать разные байтики, в том числе и нулевые.

Comment: @user7860670 отлично, я посмотрю память и что я увижу? Свою строку и следом за ней '\0'. Как я узнаю, принадлежит ли этот '\0' моей строке? А gdb вполне может знать, он же видит, что я выделил память под 3 или 4 элемента, что я кладу, может показывать мне буковки в моей памяти, так и как тогда заставить показывать мне '\0'

Comment: @KoVadim Да, я и хочу это увидеть. Ведь он мне показывает мою строку "tra", она динамически выделена. В ней так же есть '\0' но я его не вижу. Есть аналогичная переменная без '\0', как же мне их в дебаге различить, если я не знаю, в какой есть '\0' а в какой - нет

Comment: @KoVadim И самое интереное, что размер второй переменной, содержащей "tra" на 1 меньше(без \0). Но я могу псомтреть что лежит следом за пределами моей строки и это '\0'. '\0' за пределами моей памяти, потому то что  вы предложили (@user7860670) вряд ли поможет

Comment: gdb может увидеть, но не всегда. И размер памяти в 99% случаев на совести программиста (если мы говорим о си). Более того, если выделяется к примеру 3  байта, то скорее всего выделится по факту все 4 (а иногда и все 16). И узнать реальный размер будет очень сложно

Comment: *"он же видит, что я выделил память под 3 или 4 элемента"* - ничего такого он не видит, у него есть указатель на char, содержимое которого выводится как С-строка. *"Как я узнаю, принадлежит ли этот '\0' моей строке"* - ну а вот вы-то как раз знаете, что выделили память под 3 или 4 элемента, соответственно понимаете, где оканчивается буфер, в котором лежит строка. Хотите, чтобы выводилась не C-строка, а содержимое буфера - используйте string_view / array_view, а не сырые указатели.